# I facing an "if" Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) to check user credential. It is a simple login page. Appreciate for helping me

Tags: php, sql, if-statement

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
```

> After I connect to my database server, I check user credential for valid user

```
//query database for user
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc()
```

> Here the error comes, I use if else statement to check, but i get an error

```
if($row['username'] == $username && $row['password'] == $password){
        echo "Login Success !! Welcome ".$row['username'];
    } else{
        echo "Failed to login";
    }
```

Comment: what you want to do with `if {}else{}` condition in that ???

Comment: `$row = $result->fetch_assoc()` no closing `;`

Answer (score -2):

It is just a syntax error. Put the corresponding semicolon at the end of this line:

$row = $result->fetch_assoc(); // <—